# Material images android

Tags: android, generator, assets

Is there any generator of [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlm9T.jpg) images? I have seen a lot of images like that in android apps, so i think there must be a generator. I have searched for it, but found nothing. Maybe anyone know how to create such assets?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool called Material Design Background Generator that can do that for you. It's an online tool, check out this link: http://www.stringsistemas.com/materialgenerator.html

After a few random generations you can get some awesome patterns but you can't choose the palette colors unfortunately but it seems like the developer is open for suggestions.

Comment: @Maxgmer my pleasure :)